# capturar datos con con un modal desde una tabla dinamica

Tags: javascript, laravel

Buenas noches a los que me leen, quisera que me ayuden, quiero capturar los valores de una fila de una tabla y mostrarlos en un modal

aui tengo la tabla que llega desde la base de datos...

```
<tbody id="myTable">

                @foreach($actividades as $actividad)
                <tr>
                    <td id="campId<?php echo $actividad->id; ?>">{{ $actividad->id }}</td>
                    <td id="campAct<?php echo $actividad->id; ?>">{{ $actividad->activiNomb }}</td>
                    <td id="campLog<?php echo $actividad->id; ?>">{{ $actividad->logNomb }}</td>
                    <td id="campCur<?php echo $actividad->id; ?>">{{ $actividad->curNomb }}</td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <?php echo $actividad->id ?>
                           <button id="{{ $actividad->id }}" type="button"  value"<?php echo $actividad->id; ?>" class="edit btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light blue" style="margin-top:-0.8em; margin-bottom:-0.8em; float: left;">
                           <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:30px; color:#f9791e"></i> </bottom>

                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <form action="{{ action('ActividadesController@destroy', $actividad->id) }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" style="margin-top:-0.8em; margin-bottom:-0.8em;"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="font-size:30px; color:#f9791e"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                @endforeach



            </tbody>
```

y aqui esta la funcion que captura los datos y los pone pone en el modal, el cual el problema es que no me captural el id del elemento y me lo pone vacio

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
        var pr= $('.edit').val();
        var id=$(this).val();
        console.log(pr);
        var ids=$('#campId'+id).text();
        var actividad=$('#campAct'+id).text();
//      console.log(actividad);
        var logro=$('#campLog'+id).text();
        var curso=$('#campCur'+id).text();

        $('#editModal').modal('show');
        $('#modId').val(ids);
        $('#modAct').val(actividad);
        $('#modLog').val(logro);
        $('#modCur').val(curso);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas obtener el id del botón seleccionado, `val()` no es el método adecuado, tendrías que hacer uso del método [**`attr('nombreatributo')`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) para obtener el valor del atributo `id` en este caso.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id'); // this hace referencia al botón con la clase .edit
    console.log(id);
});
```

Tener en cuenta que `id` y `value` tienen el mismo valor, lo más probable que sea mejor quedarse con uno. Si es con `value` , el método `val()` si funcionaría.

Comment: oye maestro, me tomo todo el dia de ayer ya que estuve poniendo .attr('value'); en lo que estuve ingestigando, bueno... me sirvio Dios te Bendiga

Comment: ya lo hice @Dev. Joel

Comment: @srJJ _(Dado que no está claro)_ para aceptar la respuesta, debe seleccionar el check al  lado izquierdo de mi respuesta, debería marcarse de color verde.Saludos

Comment: listo... disculpa, no entendia mucho, de paso agradezco nuevamente y con una preguntita, sera que ti sabes como validar con el Aut login de laravel ?

Comment: @srJJ te invito a plantear la pregunta que desees. Igual si no soy yo habrá otro usuario que te brindará ayuda.